# ¿Cómo parsear Json con ngRepeat?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

suponiendo que tengo el siguiente `json`

```
seats = [
  {
    rows:[
      {
        "seatNUmber": "A",
        "IsAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "seatNUmber": "B",
        "IsAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "seatNUmber": "C",
        "IsAvailable": false
      },
      {
        "seatNUmber": "D",
        "IsAvailable": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    rows:[
      {
        "seatNUmber": "A",
        "IsAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "seatNUmber": "B",
        "IsAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "seatNUmber": "C",
        "IsAvailable": false
      },
      {
        "seatNUmber": "D",
        "IsAvailable": true
      }
    ]
  }
```

Quisiera saber ¿cómo puedo parsear este `json` en una lista `<ul>`?, es decir, que cada seatNumber este en un `<li>` de  la lista. Supongo que es un Loop anidado pero no logro entender de que manera poner los ng-repeat.

El resultado que quiero lograr es algo como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde cada caja representa un asiento y es un `<li>` de la lista.

Comment: ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo de cuál es el resultado que esperas?

Comment: si, ya edite la pregunta, puse una imagen mas o menos de lo que ando queriendo hacer.

Comment: ¿Quieres una única lista con todos los asientos como `li`?¿O quieres una  lista anidada con un `ul` por fila y los asientos como `li` de la lista correspondiente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los Loops aninados con `ng-repeat` funcionan como cualquier otro loop. Una analogía del `ng-repeat` utilizando un `foreach` sería:

```
forEarch(seat in seats){
  forEach(row in seat.rows){
    console.log(row);
  }
}
```

Ahora, utilizando el `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="seat in seats">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="row in seat.rows">{{$index}}{{row.seatNUmber}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```